# setting a parsed vuln to null if it cant be parsed

Tags: python, parsing, default-value

I have some logic that attempts to parse a field out of a webpage.

```
    thesev=cve.find("span", class_="label-warning").text   #should assume null if DoE
```

however, sometime this value isnt always available to be parsed.

How can i set it to null (`None`) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which package you're working with or what errors you're getting or what the rest of your script looks like, you could just use a [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) when assigning the value to `thesev`:

```
thesev = cve.find("span", class_="label-warning").text or None
```

This will evaluate if `cve.find()` has returned something and if not, then it reverts to whatever value you put after the `or`. Note: if this returns a blank string, python may see that as a value and return it instead of `None`. Again, seeing the rest of your code/the errors and/or outputs you're getting would help.